# How to express that one is making the conversation long for fun

Tags: single-word-requests

How can I tell someone that I was just making the conversation long for fun? I am looking for some American idiom to express it.

Comment: Most people don't do it for fun.

Comment: @drm65 - You have never had a conversation that you found so stimulating you looked for additional things to talk about?  Or just talked with a member of the opposite sex simply because you enjoyed doing so?

Comment: Okay, okay, I give up!  :)

Answer (score 18):

If you are pretending not to understand or misunderstand for a little fun at the expense of the other person that would be **[Teasing](http://www.answers.com/topic/teasing)**.

If you are just talking to someone with mindless chatter that is often refered to as **[Babbling](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/babbling).**

If you are just talking about things that interest one or both of you then it is often referred to as **[Chitchat](http://www.answers.com/topic/chitchat)**.

If it is a mutual session of playful verbal jabs at each other it can be referred to as **[Banter](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/banter)**

And talking with a member of the preferred sex, for fun is often called **[Flirting](http://www.bing.com/Dictionary/search?q=define%20flirt&qpvt=flitring%20definition&FORM=DTPDIA)**.

Comment: Nice. Looks like the answer

Comment: Indeed, nice list. One more: if someone is making a funny story deliberately longer they are "*telling a shaggy dog story*". http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_dog_story

Answer (score 14):

I would say that one is "drawing out" a conversation. That certainly has a meaning of "prolonging," and since it is voluntary, the implication it is at the pleasure of the actor.

Another word I would use to describe this phenomenon is "lingering."

Comment: Thanks. I guess "drawing out"/"lingering" the conversation for fun looks better.

Comment: @user395881: will you upvote this answer?

Comment: @Tom: I will! :)

Comment: "linger" is an intransitive verb, not taking an object - you "linger" (i.e. stay) you do not "linger the conversation".

Comment: @djclayworth: Fair enough. But the CONVERSATION can linger. I described this as a "phenomenon."

Comment: 'Linger' can have negative connotations.  To emphasize that the extra time was taken strictly for enjoyment use ['dally'](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dally).

Comment: @drm65: Thanks. Glad to see you on this site. In a big way.

Comment: So I'm on this site in a big way, or you're glad in a big way?  Or both? :)

Comment: @Tom BTW, I didn't get very far on BCG just because I am mostly chess there, and there aren't too many chess Qs asked there.  _I_ probably asked half of them.  As you probably can guess, I am committed to the Chess proposal, though that isn't going very far either.  So I came here, and look where I went!  Needless to say, it's a lot of fun.  Too much, sometimes.

Comment: @Tom Au Sorry my comment should have been prefixed with "@user395881". Your answer is excellent.

Answer (score 9):

You could say *I/we were just  **[shooting the breeze](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shoot_the_breeze)*** or *I/we were just **[chewing the fat](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/chew_the_fat)***.

These are idioms that imply an idle conversation which has no purpose other than entertainment or occupying time.

Comment: Nice answer, Colin.

Answer (score 2):

I could have been more succinct, but I wanted a **prolix** conversation for fun.

> [**prolix**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prolix?show=0&t=1311340273)
>
> 1 : unduly prolonged or drawn out : too long
>
> 2 : marked by or using an excess of words

Comment: Well, if you need a list of all the words meaning _wordy_...

Comment: The adjective _prolix_ has an **unfavorable** connotation, so it would not be used when a conversation is prolonged for enjoyment.

Answer (score 1):

Huh, good question. If you're looking for a response to a question like "Why is this conversation so long," witty options may include "It's the journey, not the destination," "If not this conversation, then which?" or "Good things come to those who wait." something playful/humorous should render the guy into a more docile state.

Comment: None of these are idioms, though.  I don't know if there are any.

Answer (score 1):

I would call it, "spinning out" the conversation; or in the past tense, "The conversation was drawn out" works better

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to a narrative joke, it's known as a [Shaggy Dog Story](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shaggy_dog_story). You can find concrete media examples of a Shaggy Dog Story [here](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/ShaggyDogStory).